# Page accessible only if logged in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Hello Stackoverflowers

Im new to PHP and im trying to make a members area for my testpage. I have made a successful register and login page, but now when I changed the code so if I log in correctly it redirects my to a page, and if I log in with wrong information it send me to a different page. However the members area is accessible if you type the location in the address-bar. Now, here's what I need help with, When someone tries to access that location without being logged in it should say "Access denied" but when you log in, it should redirect you to the members area and all it content is shown.

Here is my code:

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  $db = 'Data';

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

 if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){
      header("Location: loggedin.php");
      exit();
    } else {
      echo 'Anv&auml;ndarnamn eller l&ouml;senord st&auml;mmer ej med informationen i databasen, var sn&auml;ll f&ouml;rs&ouml;k igen <br>';
      echo '<a href="login.php">G&aring; tillbaka</a> Eller <a href="signup.php">Registrera dig</a>';

      exit();
    }
  }
?>


<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Logga in</title>

    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div>bababa<span>bababa</span></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="login">
      <form method="post" action="login.php">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Anv&auml;ndarnamn" name="username" required><br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="L&ouml;senord" name="password" required><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Logga in">
      </form>
        </div>
  </div>

  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

signup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(".name").focus(function(){
  $(".name-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function(){
  $(".name-help").slideUp(500);
});

$(".email").focus(function(){
  $(".email-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function(){
  $(".email-help").slideUp(500);
});



</script>

</head>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Registrera er h&auml;r</h1>
  <p>Detta &auml;r ett test-formul&auml;r f&ouml;r Webbutvecklingsprojektet. Skriv ditt namn h&auml;r
  under och om allt funkar r&auml;tt skall systemet lagra ditt namn i en MySQL databas.</p>

  <form class="form" name="form" method="post" action="add.php">

     <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Anv&auml;ndarnamn" required>

     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="L&ouml;senord" required>

 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>


    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Registrera dig">

  </form>

  <h3>
    Allm&auml;nt & regler:
  </h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Maximalt 2GB Lagring</li>
    <li>Du m&aring;ste skriva f&ouml;r- och efternamn</li>
    <li>Databasen lagrar bara upp till 60 anv&auml;ndare</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p class="optimize">
</p>
</html>
```

And last: loggedin.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  $db = 'Data';

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

   if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   die("Please login");
} else {
echo 'Du &auml;r inloggad';
}
?>
```

FTR: I tried the if isset but even when I logged in correctly the same message shows up: Please log in, how should I fix this?

Im a newbie at this so help me a bit extra

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please convert the text to english so that the rest of us can have an easier time tracking  the comments/output?

Comment: I would like to point out that your SQL Statement `SELECT * FROM Project WHERE username='$username' ...` is an easy target for attackers. Once you figure out how the PHP part works, i'd strongly recommend reading up on something called **SQL Injection**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Cookies` or `SESSION` to do this.

When a user is authenticated, before redirecting to homeS page you should set a session variable like this: `$_SESSION['id']=$user_id;`. And if you want to set `COOKIES` so that user can access his account directly even after closing browser, you can set it like this `setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // for 1 day`.

So, now at the start of every page you need to start session `session_start()` to get the `session` value you set during login.
If a `user_id` of any user info exists in the session it will automatically use that info to access the page.

Now considering you want that the user is automatically redirected to login page/ACCESS DENIED if he tries to access home page.. You can do this by checking if the session user_info or cookie exist or not...if it doesn't redirect him to the login page or any error page as per you need...

In your code, before `header("Location: loggedin.php");` create a session `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`. And keep in mind to `session_start()` on every page, where `$_SESSION` value is going to be used..

Comment: Hey, Moid Mohd, I tried what you told me and the whole page is going blank, please help the code:  `if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  header("Location: loggedin.php");
  exit();` And I have not changed anything at the loggedin.php page

Comment: when is it going blank..?

Comment: The login.php is going blank after I entered the $_SESSION code

Comment: Oops, my fault, I didnt put ; This worked perfectly thank you Moid Mohd!

Comment: And for your redirection to home page or error page you can use this `session` value to check if it has a value..else redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is to redirect to a login page if user is not logged in.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, it redirects me to the login page even when I enter everything correctly.

Comment: I'm to tired to do this now but the basic idea is: Decide wheter user is logged in or not -> if is, set a session variable like $_SESSION['username'] -> then check if  $_SESSION['username'] is set and if not redirect to login.php.

From what I see in your code you never set $_SESSION['username'] and therefore it will never pass the if. When user is logged in, set  $_SESSION['username'] :)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the if isset but even when I logged in correctly the same message shows up: Please log in, how should I fix this?

OK, when you log in succesfully, just before you redirect the user to the other page:

```
header("Location: loggedin.php");
```

you've to assign a session variable to the user, like this (for example. It depends how you want to identify them).

```
$_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
```

I think this is enought

By the way, please, don't use mysql_query
Use instead: mysqli extension. 
(for more [information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php))

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have started the session `session_start`, but you haven't actually set the `$_SESSION['username']`. You need to set the session variable in between these two line.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){
  // set session variable here
  header("Location: loggedin.php");
  exit();
}
```

Make sure you use the `session_start()` on the top of every page so that your able to check if the person who is viewing the page is logged in.

Also just another tip `mysql_connect` has been deprecated [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), you can use `mysqli` or `PDO` which escapes things automatically for you.

Comment: Hey Andre, I tried that, but it gave me an error, is this how I should enter it? `$res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){
      $_SESSION['username'];
  header("Location: loggedin.php");
  exit(); `

Comment: To make it simple you can just use the following code `$_SESSION['username'] = "logged_in";`